# Laravel 5.1 - How to load content from database for Master Page

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm making an administrable website in Laravel. I have a custom class that loads the content of a page / widget from a database and returns HTML.

```
/**
 * Loads a page content from the database
 * 
 * @param Id of the page, it can be a number or class constant
 * @return html
 */
public function pageContent($id)
{
    $content = DB::table('pages')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    return $content->content;
}
```

Let's say the website administrator put in that page something like:

"All Rights reserved, blablabla 2015, Contact Us: 488 889 77 88"

And I want it to appear in the website footer. Some of my master page code is.

```
<body>

    @include('layouts.mainmenu')

    @yield('body')

    <div class="footer">
        {{ I WANT TO HAVE THE FOOTER FROM THE DATABASE HERE! }}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>

    @yield('bottom-js')

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function is inside your **HomeController**

HomeController:

```
  public function pageContent($id)
 {
   $content = DB::table('pages')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
   return $content;
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $content = $this->pageContent();
    return view('your_master_blade', compact('content'));
  }
```

View inside your master blade:

```
<body>

@include('layouts.mainmenu')

@yield('body')

<div class="footer">
    @foreach($content as $cont)
       {{$cont->id}}
         //so on and so forth
    @endforeach
    {{ I WANT TO HAVE THE FOOTER FROM THE DATABASE HERE! }}
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>

@yield('bottom-js')
```

Comment: But where do I call the pageContent() function? In every controller for every view? so it appears always in the website's footer?

Comment: So your expected output must be in only one view it will load the content and for the others footer must not load the content? Am I right?

Comment: No, the idea is that the footer is inside the master page, therefore appearing in every single section the user visits.

Comment: What's the route or view of your master page?

Comment: views / layout / master.blade.php

Comment: Can I see your routes?

Comment: Well I just started developing this site not long ago, the only route is the one for the homepage: Route::get('/', [
 'as' => 'home_path',
 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
]);

Comment: Can I see your HomeController as well? Include that in your question

Comment: Keeping it simple, it contains: public function index()
 {
  return view('home');
 }

Comment: I think the solution is to use View Composers, since I need that content to appear in most of pages! :)